# How to disable expand animation on appearance of cairo dock?

Tags: dock, cairo-dock

i have set visibility of main dock to hide, so whenever i move the move to bottom of screen, dock appears with expand animation.

how to make dock just appear with any animation like docky or awn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cairo 2.2.1,

> Settings -> Visibility of the main dock -> Effect used to hide the dock to **Fade out**

Answer (score 1):

You can easily configure Cairo Dock by right click on the dock and choosing 'Configure'.

From [this tutorial](http://www.glx-dock.org/ww_page.php?p=Tutorial-Customisation&lang=en) you can learn what setting are available. The dock can have several modes of appearance listed under the settings for "Visibility". There you can e.g. choose a static or a panel mode or define how the dock interacts with opened windows. You best try out the several modes to see what meets your needs.

From the icon settings for [Animations and Effects](http://www.glx-dock.org/ww_page.php?p=Tutorial-Customisation&lang=en#13-Animations%20and%20effects) a zoom factor of 1.00 also stops sideway expanding animation of the dock.

Comment: In Cairo 2.2.1,I'm unable to find 'Animation and Effects' rather 'Icons Animation and Effects' is available but that's used for icon's animation settings.